# Do all objects have to have the same info in them in json?

Tags: json

Do all "objects" (I hope thats what they are called) have to have the same info in them. my example that I am working with.

```
{
        "name": "Grapes",
        "purchase_price":[
            {"Pierres's": 60},
            {"JojaMart": 75},
            {"Traveling Cart": null}
        ],
        "sell_price":[
            {"Base": 80},
            {"Silver": 100},
            {"Gold": 120},
            {"Iridium": 160}
        ],
        "is_multi_harvest": false
    }
```

And this is another example where you can only "buy" an item from a different person and not the others.

```
{
        "name": "Ancient Fruit",
        "purchase_price":[
            {"Pierres's": null},
            {"JojaMart": null},
            {"Traveling Cart": 1000},
            {"Oasis": null}
        ],
        "sell_price":[
            {"Base": 550},
            {"Silver": 684},
            {"Gold": 825},
            {"Iridium": 1100}
        ],
        "is_multi_harvest": false,
        "notes": null
    }
```

so in both examples, can I just get rid of the ones with "null" for them since you can't purchase it from them at all, or must I have them and give them this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing in the [JSON Specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) requires all elements in a list to have the same shape.

JSON is a set of rules about how to express data, what you put in it is all on you.